# Strange warning about conversion between 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c, list, sequential

I use CLion by the way.

```
int ch;
printf("Insert the operation you want to execute: ");
scanf("%d", &ch); //HERE
```

I declare ch as an integer variable and with *scanf* and *%d* and I want the user to insert a value to insert in the ch variable but HERE a warning pops up and says: *" 'scanf' used to convert a string to an integer value"*

I can't understand why...

Here is the entire code, as requested in comments:
(the code is modified because I changed it since yesterday)

```
typedef unsigned int boolean;

struct list{
float * buffer;
int size;
int head;
int tail;
};

int getsize();
float getvalue();
void init(struct list*, int);
boolean suf_insert(struct list*, float, int);
boolean pre_insert(struct list*, float, int);
void visit(struct list*);

int main(){

struct list listA;
struct list listB;
int size=0;

int ch;

while(1){

    printf("Sequential Lists operations\n");
    printf("1.  Insert the size of the array\n");
    printf("2.  Initialize the list A\n");
    printf("3.  Initialize the list B\n");
    printf("4.  \n");
    printf("5.  \n");
    printf("6.  \n");
    printf("7.  \n");

    printf("\nInsert the operation you want to execute: ");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch(ch){
        case 1: size=getsize();
            break;
        case 2: init(&listA, size);
            break;
        case 3: init(&listB, size);
            break;
        case 4: getvalue();
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;

        default: printf("\nInvalid command. Retry\n");
            break;
    }
}

}
int getsize(){
int size;
printf("Insert the size of the list you want to create: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
return size;
}

float getvalue(){
float value;
printf("The value you want to insert: ");
scanf("%f", &value);

return value;
}

void init(struct list * ptr, int size) {

if (size != 0) {
    ptr->buffer = (float *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    ptr->size = size;
    ptr->head = 0;
    ptr->tail = 0;
} else {
    printf("\nBefore continue, insert the size.\n");
}
}

boolean suf_insert(struct list * ptr, float value, int size){

    if(((ptr->tail + 1) % ptr->size) != ptr->head && size!=0) {

        ptr->buffer[ptr->tail] = value;
        ptr->tail = (ptr->tail + 1) % ptr->size;

        return TRUE;
    } else {

        return FALSE;
    }
}

boolean pre_insert(struct list * ptr, float value, int size){

if(((ptr->tail + 1) % ptr->size) != ptr->head && size!=0){

        ptr->head = (ptr->head + ptr->size - 1) % ptr->size;
        ptr->buffer[ptr->head] = value;

        return TRUE;
}else{

        return FALSE;
}
}

void visit(struct list * ptr){

int position;
for(position=ptr->head; position!=ptr->tail; position=(position+1)%ptr-     >size){
    printf("%f", ptr->buffer[position]);
}

}
```

IT SEEMS LIKE I HAVE TO REPEAT: this code ISN'T PERFECT, maybe the exact opposite! I'm still working on it!

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not telling us everything...[mcve], please.

Comment: Ok I tried... The rest of the code doesn't have anything in common with the problem.

Comment: I afraid it is not enough. We need a complete snippet that you can compile and see the warning.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the verbatim error/warning message.

Comment: That doesn't seem minimal... I didn't finish so the code wouldn't work! I included the screen but I don't think I can do better. I hope is enough. :)

Comment: OK, the screenshot is suggesting that it's not a compiler, but the IDE warning. Well, it's nice. I guess in order to get rid of it you should check the return value of `scanf` (if the IDE is really that smart as it pretends to be)

Comment: I did... (?) " 'scanf' used to convert a string to an integer value"

Comment: I'll be back in a moment, thanks anyway for now

Comment: Try `int valuesred = scanf("%d", &ch);` and see if the warnign disapear. But you can probably ignore this warning which sees rather strange to me..

Comment: Posting a screenshot for a single line of _text_ is not justified.  You could have simply transcribed the text.  You have partially transcribed it - but omitted perhaps the important part!

Comment: Been told to put the screenshot and so I did... Read all the comments! (I also said that it doesn't seem minimal)

Comment: Nope, the comments did not tell you to post a screenshot. The first comment advised to post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you read the link?

Comment: I would be more concerned about the very last line in the screenshot "Too few arguments, expected 2. Missing ';' ". And I would also be concerned about function `getsize(int size)` which overwrites the argument passed to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Ok i’ll copy paste the entire code

Comment: @WeatherVane i said that it’s not finished! What about concentrate on the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is clear about why; you have omitted the part that says "*function will not report conversion errors*".  However it is also clearly nonsense : `strtol()` does not report conversion errors either - it simply returns zero if there is a conversion error - but that is indistinguishable from a successful conversion of "0".

With `scanf()` at least the return value is an unambiguous indication of success or otherwise. It is true that `scanf()` does not report conversion errors, it reports a count of successful conversions, so when there is only one conversion as in this case, a return value of zero is exactly reporting the conversion error.

The "warning" is generated by your IDE not your compiler and is merely advice (bad advice IMO) - you can clearly choose to ignore the advice.

But you should at least *check* the return value from `scanf()`. If `scanf()` fails, the value of `ch` is undefined.  An advantage of `strtol()` is that on failure it returns at least a defined value - zero - and in this *specific* case at least, zero is an invalid value, so it has merit; but not for the reason suggested in the warning perhaps.

Comment: I don't think _advice is more the opinion of *whoever wrote your IDE*_ is correct. The check originates from here : https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ERR34-C.+Detect+errors+when+converting+a+string+to+a+number

Comment: @Vasan : I have removed that in a significant edit.  That said, the author of the IDE chose to integrate that coding standard into the IDE, so is at least his shared opinion.  Neither solution is a robust error check of valid in range input.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer!